# mdadm 10 far raid uneven read speed

Tags: dd, mdadm

Why sequential read speed from raid 10 growth only with very huge `bs`(>100MB, `dd` parameter).
Having raid:

```
/dev/md127:
Version : 1.2
Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 46875009024 (44703.49 GiB 48000.01 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 11718752256 (11175.87 GiB 12000.00 GB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

             State : clean
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : far=2
        Chunk Size : 1024K

Consistency Policy : bitmap
```

I expect sequential read speed at least 100MB*n_drives=800+MB/sec.
But:

```bsh
dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=10240k count=1000 iflag=direct
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
10485760000 bytes (10 GB, 9.8 GiB) copied, 14.2918 s, 734 MB/s

iostat -zxs 1
Device             tps      kB/s    rqm/s   await  areq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
md127          2880.00 737280.00     0.00    0.00   256.00    0.00   0.00
sda             360.00  92160.00     0.00    5.21   256.00    1.24  70.80
sdb             360.00  92160.00     0.00    5.05   256.00    1.14  74.80
sdc             367.00  93952.00     0.00    5.25   256.00    1.26  76.80
sdd             368.00  94208.00     0.00    6.46   256.00    1.70  80.80
sde             360.00  92160.00     0.00    5.53   256.00    1.31  75.60
sdf             362.00  92672.00     0.00    6.15   256.00    1.54  72.40
sdg             364.00  93184.00     0.00    5.18   256.00    1.24  73.20
sdh             364.00  93184.00     0.00    5.73   256.00    1.40  70.40
```

If I test single drive:

```bsh
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1024k count=1000 iflag=direct
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 4.25743 s, 246 MB/s

iostat -xs /dev/sda 1
Device             tps      kB/s    rqm/s   await  areq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
sda             868.00 222208.00     0.00    2.79   256.00    0.70 100.00
```

Only when I set `bs` very huge - I can gain read speed similar to single speed * n_drives:

```
dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=1024000k count=30 iflag=direct
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280000 bytes (31 GB, 29 GiB) copied, 16.2737 s, 1.9 GB/s

iostat -dxs 1
Device             tps      kB/s    rqm/s   await  areq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
md127         10115.00 2341348.00     0.00    0.00   231.47    0.00   0.00
sda            1077.00 259848.00   187.00  153.82   241.27  163.51  95.20
sdb            1077.00 260612.00   197.00  162.94   241.98  173.33  99.20
sdc            1083.00 262412.00   197.00  160.82   242.30  171.96  98.40
sdd            1067.00 258568.00   195.00  170.78   242.33  180.09 100.00
sde            1086.00 262416.00   195.00  159.38   241.64  170.90  98.40
sdf            1077.00 260360.00   189.00  155.88   241.75  165.71  96.40
sdg            1073.00 259076.00   197.00  160.96   241.45  170.56  98.00
sdh            1085.00 260872.00   191.00  163.61   240.44  175.34  99.60
```

My workload contains mostly sequential reads, but I'm not sure that app will issue IO reads with such huge sizes.

Since test is performed on block device directly - this mean that problem is not in FS.
`areq-sq` in all cases near the same, but `%util` is lower for raid, does this mean that raid has the problems with generating requests(but aqu-sz is very huge for raid, also why?)?
How to find the reason?

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
Linux 5.4.0-67-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:03:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
cat /sys/block/md127/queue/scheduler
none
```

**EDIT** *I was **wrong** about `>100MB` in my first row.*
I've made some experiments with different bs(to check aligned reads variants):

```
dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=8M count=3000 iflag=direct
25165824000 bytes (25 GB, 23 GiB) copied, 33.1877 s, 758 MB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=16M count=300 iflag=direct
5033164800 bytes (5.0 GB, 4.7 GiB) copied, 4.71832 s, 1.1 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=18M count=1000 iflag=direct
18874368000 bytes (19 GB, 18 GiB) copied, 18.4601 s, 1.0 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=20M count=500 iflag=direct
10485760000 bytes (10 GB, 9.8 GiB) copied, 10.0867 s, 1.0 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=32M count=300 iflag=direct
10066329600 bytes (10 GB, 9.4 GiB) copied, 7.29756 s, 1.4 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=128M count=100 iflag=direct
13421772800 bytes (13 GB, 12 GiB) copied, 8.27345 s, 1.6 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=256M count=100 iflag=direct
26843545600 bytes (27 GB, 25 GiB) copied, 15.5701 s, 1.7 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=512M count=100 iflag=direct
53687091200 bytes (54 GB, 50 GiB) copied, 28.9437 s, 1.9 GB/s

dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=1G count=32 iflag=direct
34359738368 bytes (34 GB, 32 GiB) copied, 18.36 s, 1.9 GB/s
```

Despite it is still hard to understand why speed grows with bs growing(for example from 256M to 512M), it shows not bad read speed starting from `bs=32M`.

Comment: What is the aqu-sz and %util with bs=8M?

Comment: aqu-sz: (0.6:0.9), %util: (76:80)

Answer (score 1):

Your chunk size is 1M so with 8 drives, your stripe size is 8M. If you issue a direct IO read of 10M, then you are asking for 1 and a fraction stripes, so it will take as long as reading two stripes to finish.  If you are going to use direct IO, you will want to keep your bs to an even multiple of the stripe size.  Normal applications also don't use direct IO, but go through the cache, so you may want to make sure the readahead value is big enough ( /sys/block/mdxxx/queue ).  Going with a smaller chunk size when you create the array might be a good idea.  I thought the default these days was 512k, but it used to be 64k and I'm not sure why it was increased.

Comment: Aligned read also shows not very good results:
```
dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=8M count=3000 iflag=direct
3000+0 records in
3000+0 records out
25165824000 bytes (25 GB, 23 GiB) copied, 32.7052 s, 769 MB/s
```

Comment: Current readahead is: `cat /sys/block/md127/queue/read_ahead_kb \n 16384`

Comment: just tried with 32768(x2) `read_ahead_kb`, then with 163840(x10) - same speed `dd if=/dev/md127 of=/dev/null bs=8M count=3000 iflag=direct`. 
Also, your point about cache is right in general, but in my workload read data volume can not fit into cache size, so it will be always reads from HDD.